# Audio alternatives for Raspberry Pi 400

Tags: pi-4, audio, bluetooth, ubuntu, raspberry-pi-os

So as you all know, the Raspberry Pi 400 does NOT have an audio jack, which is pretty annoying especially when I need to get audio output from it.

Can I connect to a Raspberry Pi 3B via Bluetooth from the Pi 400, and use the Pi 3B's audio jack as output from the Pi 400?

If so, how can I do this? I'm kind of a noob at this type of stuff, so help is appreciated.
(I am planning to buy a Bluetooth speaker later this summer, but I am really impatient and I really want to play RetroPie with audio! :p)

My main operating system is Ubuntu MATE on the Pi 400, and I have a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS on the Pi 3B.

Comment: The straightforward of getting audio from a Pi 400 I would think would be via a USB to audio jack adapter. e.g. https://thepihut.com/products/usb-audio-adapter-works-with-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 2):

The Pi 400 can play audio though HDMI.

If your monitor has an audio jack you can plug your speakers/headphones in there and you should be able to get audio that way.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought my Raspberry Pi 400 and have been having trouble connecting to my bluetooth speaker. If you're going to buy speakers, you might just want to get them with usb connection.